# Can't find in my viewport but it shows in the outliner

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, sculpting, outliner

Can anyone help, I was sculpting a human full figure. So decided bring in my eyes, I went into object mode to add a sphere and hide the figure I was sculpting pushing the H button so I could work on the eye well. Finished  with the eye, now to put in the right place on the figure I sculpted but I can't unhide it even with the alt H but the object shows in the outliner .Did everything to make it unhide but it keeps hiding from me. Please anyone at my aid as soon as possible? [image]

Comment: Seems like the other objets are in a different layer.

Comment: I can't find the object.. it's hidden in the viewport but visible in the outliner

Answer (score 1):

Trying pressing the Tilde key (~) to show all layers and then pressing Alt + H to unhide all objects. It looks like there are objects in other layers which could be where the missing object is.

Comment: It's the lamp and camera I moved to the layer. And I have checked the layer but it won't unhide